# How get string inside bracket "()" using cmake regex

Tags: regex, cmake

I am trying to get the string inside '( )' by using CMake regex.
here is the example which I tried:

```
set(STR "example(arg1,arg2)")
string(REGEX MATCH "^\(.*\)$" ARG_STR ${STR})
```

expected: `arg1,arg2`, but I got `example(arg1,arg2)`
Please guide me how to fix this.

Comment: Does `string(REGEX MATCH "(?<=\\()[^()]+(?=\\))" ARG_STR ${STR})` work?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew , I got an error: 
 ` string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCH failed to compile regex
  "(?<=\()[^()]+(?=\))". `

Comment: Ok, then you might use  a grouping approach, `string(REGEX MATCH "\\(([^()]*)\\)" _ ${STR})` and then use `${CMAKE_MATCH_1}` to access that captured value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it works. but the bracket also matched.

Comment: It is matched but the group contains no brackets, just the content between `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capturing group with a pattern lie

```
string(REGEX MATCH "\\(([^()]*)\\)" _ ${STR})
```

Then, you can access the contents using `${CMAKE_MATCH_1}`, e.g.

```
message("ARGS_STR: ${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
```

See [`CMAKE` reference details](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html):

> *New in version 3.9*: All regular expression-related commands, including e.g. [**if(MATCHES)**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#command:if), save subgroup matches in the variables **[**CMAKE_MATCH_**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MATCH_n.html#variable:CMAKE_MATCH_%3Cn%3E)** for `<n>` 0..9.

Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l1OcPr/1).

Answer (score 0):

The question was already answered correctly. But I'd like to show an easy way to also add error checking in case the regex fails.

```
set(STR "example(arg1,arg2)")

if (${STR} MATCHES "\\(([^()]*)\\)")
    message(STATUS ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Regex failed!")
endif()
```